# Gradle density split for tvdpi and 560dpi

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

**How to use gradle density split to generate apks compatible with tvdpi and 560dpi devices?**

I use gradle density split in my google play application and I noticed that no matter what I change it is not generating *android:screenDensity="213"* (for tvdpi) and *android:screenDensity="560"* (for nexus 6) inside  *compatible-screens* element and so my apks are not compatible with some popular devices.

For testing purposes I created new application in Android Studio (1.2b) using gradle build tools version 1.1.0 with following build.gradle file for my app module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.marek.densitysplittest"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
splits {
    density {
        enable true
        compatibleScreens 'small', 'normal', 'large', 'xlarge'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

It is generating apks for *ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi* **and NOT for** *tvdpi, 400dpi, 560dpi*.

However I have found [density split example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/8a342dc062e41182d8c887ac413697c405324a7c/build-system/integration-test/samples/densitySplit/build.gradle) that suggests it is possible to use values like "560dpi":

```
splits {
    density {
      enable true
      exclude "ldpi", "tvdpi", "xxxhdpi", "400dpi", "560dpi"
      compatibleScreens 'small', 'normal', 'large', 'xlarge'
    }
}
```

I have also imported that project and removed *exclude* from build file and still they weren't created (*tvdpi, 400dpi and 560dpi*).

I have also tried *reset()* with *include* and effect is the same - 
none of decompiled apks contain proper *compatible-screens* tag with screen density I need.